# Performance implication of creating tables in SQLite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

In SQLite, there is a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` clause.

I cannot find a reason why this is bad to use regarding performance.

For every single SQLite query, I will be calling that beforehand just to make things easier.

Since SQLite is extremely fast, what is wrong with doing this? Is it just bad practice VS actually having a performance bottleneck?

I am using this with PHP 7 if that helps

Comment: if not exists have to check internal list of tables to find out whether table is there or not, it can be either O(N) or O(logN) or even amortized O(1) operation depends on internal implementation, but the problem here is that you want to do something actually useless for each query, so even if operation is fast, lets say 1ms, you will add 1*N ms latency, is it acceptable - depends on your use case

Comment: "For every single SQLite query, I will be calling that beforehand just to make things easier." I wonder how you are using your database. Why do you have to create tables at all for a every query? Sounds pretty odd

Answer (score 0):

Use a database migration tool like https://phinx.org/, it can run your DML's at deploy time. Database modifications should not be done at runtime by a consumer, even if the DML execution time is negligible